# I Need create an html page that reads a XML file in a CD-R. How I can do that?

Tags: javascript, html

I made an html website that will be running in a CD-R (this will be a manual).
I have the page created and everything is working good, but at this moment I'm having some problems for opening a XML file.

My question is, is this possible, since It will be running in a CD Drive?
Thank you

This is what I have:

```
function testing()
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "teste.txt", true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            var allText = rawFile.responseText;
            alert(allText);
        }
        else
            alert("erro no xml");
    }

    rawFile.send();
}
```

This works fine in for example: localhost/path
But i want it to work in a path like c:\path\

Comment: Google Chrome does not allow Ajax requests on local files, so that won't work with that browser, unfortunately. On Firefox, it'll work fine. Running it on a CD is no different than your hard drive, if it's served with the `file:///` protocol.

Comment: use an <input type=file> to allow the user to load a file from anywhere their drive system can reach. you might also try sync ajax (file:///s won't change status to trigger ORSC) , or, since it's an xml document, a hidden iframe.

Comment: @blex That's pretty interesting that Firefox would allow that. Seems like a security hole to me - it only seems to allow requests from the current directory or deeper, so you can't go backwards. But if you put an HTML file on your C: root and open it, then it looks like javascript can pick up any file off of the filesystem.

Comment: @JoeEnos That's right, it has access to the current folder and sub-folders. Placing the file at the root (C://) gives you full access to the hard drive on Firefox. It's kind of a hole, but the file can't be aware of surrounding files, it needs to know where they are and also their names + extension. So it's not likely to cause a lot of harm.

Comment: @blex I can easily see an instance where a malicious person just looks for a whole list of common sensitive files - like your registry files, or just looping through a few thousand common usernames to look for user settings for common applications. It could do this over and over until it gets some hits, then transmit that data somewhere, and this would all be invisible to the user unless they happen to have the Network tab open in the dev tools. Obviously, the solution is just don't put anything at C:\ and then open it, but I'd still feel better if it just wouldn't allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying your source files a little bit by turning it into JSON, you could use JSONP. Here's a simple example:

```
<button onclick="go();">Click me</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function go() {
        var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
        scriptTag.src = "someText.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
    }
    function jsonCallback(txt) {
        console.log(txt);
    }
</script>
```

File: someText.js:

```
jsonCallback("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Seems like the most robust solution (But shouldn't the file extention be `.js`? It's a function call, not just an object anymore). Additionally, this link could help : [Convert XML to JSON with JavaScript - by David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json).

Comment: @blex Yes, thanks. I was thinking about something else when I wrote that.